# AutoNumeric change value

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to make my value to have thousand separators and such, but I don't understand how to use jquery and how it works.

I want to make my value from 1000 to 1,000

and I tried using AutoNumeric like this but failed

```
var autonumeric = new AutoNumeric.multiple(".form-control");
```

This is the form where I want to change the value type:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="total" class="label-control" id="labelsubtotal">Total : </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input type="text" value="" style="text-align: right;" class="form-control" id="grandTotal" name="grandTotal" disabled>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how I import AutoNumeric:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/autonumeric-next/src/AutoNumeric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Basically this is what I want to do  :
[image]

I want the result format changed into currency format

I succeeded in changing only 1 value, this is what I did:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){

$(function sum() {
    console.log($('.calc'))
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('.calc').each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $("#subTotal").val(sum);
    let subTotal = new AutoNumeric("#subTotal");
})();

function calculateSubTotal() {
    var subtotal = $("#subTotal").val();
    $("#subTotalDiscount").val(subtotal - (Math.round(($("#inputDiscount").val() / 100) * subtotal)));
    var subtotal_discount = parseInt($("#subTotalDiscount").val());
    $("#subTotalTax").val(Math.round(($("#inputTax").val() / 100) * subtotal_discount));
    var subtotal_tax = parseInt($("#subTotalTax").val());
    var pph = $("#inputpph").val();
    $("#SubTotalpph").val(Math.round(parseInt($("#inputpph").val()*subtotal_discount)));
    var subtotal_pph = parseInt($("#SubTotalpph").val());
    var grandtotal = subtotal_discount + subtotal_tax + subtotal_pph;
    $("#grandTotal").val(grandtotal);
    }
})
</script>
```

I'm lost right now.

Comment: Your `.float` input has attribute `disabled`. It's ok?

Comment: hey i just updated my question so it a bit detailed and that form is only to output the result that happen in my js code that i just put

Comment: right now i cant change the format of my `#subTotalDiscount` ,if i do it like `#subTotal` the value wont show in my localhost

Answer (score 0):

Also exists a little bit another way to do it. Do next and look what you'll get(one requirement - you need to give number value only):

**JS**

```
    $('#grandTotal').on('input',function(){

            var number, s_number, f_number;

            number  = $('#grandTotal').val();
            s_number = number.replace(/,/g,'');
            f_number = formatNumber(s_number);

            console.info(f_number);
            $('#grandTotal').val(f_number);
    }); 

function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
}
```

But, if you want just convert value without changing it dynamically then just add this in your attached `*.js`:

```
var number, f_number;
    number  = $('#grandTotal').val(); 
    f_number = formatNumber(number);

    console.info(f_number);
    $('#grandTotal').val(f_number);

function formatNumber(num) {
  return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
}
```

Comment: The whole point of AutoNumeric is that you don't need to do those string-replace functions. AutoNumeric is supposed to do all this transparently, so while it's displaying 1.456,99 €, behind the scenes it hands over the correct value 1456.99  It used to work very well with version 1.9.4, thereafter they changed the way the function loads and works. I am still trying to understand the new way and will post an answer once I have figured it out. The documentation is rather short of useful examples.

Comment: @Luftwaffle, it's so funny to use the whole third-party JS library only for this common task. IMHO, you don't need to use that JS library at all.

Comment: 0

Well it depends on the situation. If you only have one value to convert, it certainly wouldn't make sense. But if you're dealing with a whole bunch of numbers that needs converting back and forth, it makes perfect sense to use AutoNumeric. I have used it successfully for several currency-heavy pages. In the old incarnation you just needed to declare a class and like magic those numbers would display in their correct format. When you're dealing with multiple currencies and formats, it is pretty useful and saves you a lot of time.